# Computing Confidence Intervals Using Randomization Distribution

Tags: confidence-interval, permutation-test

I am confused about how to generate a CI using the randomization distribution (not sure if this is bootstrapping, but I am new and confused).

Suppose I am testing for the difference in means in a paired comparison experiment and say the sample size is 5. If I wanted to compute a p-value using the randomization distribution, I would calculate all 32 permutations and then compute the proportion of randomized test values greater than the observed values and multiply by two, making easy intuition.

How do I compute a confidence interval?

Comment: Min - Max with confidence of 30/32 =93.75%

Comment: One of the top two results [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/permutation-test+confidence-interval) may be what you are after?